# Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia Drivers Crash System!

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Every time my system is using OpenGL or anything to do with my graphics card other than booting (using xorg driver, nothing else works) the system just freezes and I can only control the mouse.

Then shortly after the mouse stop working.

This happens frequently so i uninstalled Ubuntu, but I would like to see if there is a solution that will get me running again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a temporary fix, you can just press alt+ctrl+f1 and type "sudo killall Xorg" and login again, but other wise, I'd advise using another driver from linux-drivers-nonfree (easily accessible from software center>edit>software sources>additional drivers) and try to find something that works. If it fails to apply, make sure you have them installed, though. Look them up in the software center by searching for "additional drivers". Alternately you can try to have ubuntu diagnose and attempt to install optional/recommended drivers that are not included by default by typing in "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall".